# Is there an easy way to revert an entire P4 changelist?

Tags: version-control, perforce

Let's say I checked in a changelist (in Perforce) with lots of files and I'd like to revert the entire changelist.  Is there an easy way to "revert" the entire changelist in one fell swoop?

Currently I do something like this for each file in the changelist:

- p4 sync //path/to/file#n (where "n" is the previous version of the file)
- cp file file#n
- p4 sync //path/to/file
- p4 edit //path/to/file
- cp file#n file
- rm file#n

As you can imagine, this is quite cumbersome for a large changelist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The posted answers provide correct answers, but note also that there is an actual menu option in P4V to do this for you now. It's in the latest 2008.2 Beta, and so should be officially released the the next week or three.

This [link](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/beta/index.html) gives details.

It should be a lot simpler to use than the earlier answers, but I've not had the opportunity to try it myself yet.

**Update** This has now been fully released. See [Perforce downloads](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I just tried out this beta version of P4V and can confirm that it does have a "back out submitted changelist" feature which does exactly this. Since this is an official Perforce feature rather than a third-party script, I think this should be accepted this as the official answer.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.tilander.org/aurora/2007/06/reverting-a-perforce-changelis.html) looks interesting. I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried it and it worked great!  While I couldn't get the P4V integration working on my Mac, running the script via the command line worked fine.

Comment: In case the blog post you linked to goes down, here's a direct link to the script in Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/p4scripts/source/browse/trunk/src/p4revert.py

Comment: Also, one note: the python script is (currently) saved in DOS format so you'll need to convert to unix line endings for it to work correctly on unix-based systems such as linux and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer from Perforce is at http://kb.perforce.com/UserTasks/ManagingFile..Changelists/RevertingSub..Changelists but the procedure is not all that much easier than the one you suggest. The script suggested by @ya23 looks better.

Comment: Yeah with a changelist with just "edits" it's simpler, but once you throw adds and deletes in there, it can get tricky to do manually.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the awk step does not work for me.  I'm running from a Windows environment with emulated Unix command line tools.  However, the following does work:

```
p4 describe -s [changelist_number] | grep // | sed "s/\.\.\. //" | sed "s/#.*//"  | p4 -ztag -x - where | grep "... path " | sed "s/\.\.\. path //"
```

Here are possible locations to get Unix command line tools in a Windows environment:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/?source=typ_redirect
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I want to delete an entire changelist. so I use the following script (notice that it also deletes the changelist's shelve and the changelist itself. if you only want to revert, copy the relevant lines).
Also, make sure the sed applies to your version of p4.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
echo "usage: $(basename $0) changelist"
    exit 1
fi

CHANGELIST=$1

#make sure changelist exist.
p4 describe -s $CHANGELIST > /dev/null # set -e will exit automatically if fails

p4 shelve -d -c $CHANGELIST 2> /dev/null || true # changelist can be shelveless
files_to_revert=$(p4 opened 2> /dev/null | grep "change $CHANGELIST" | sed "s/#.*//g")
if [[ -n "$files_to_revert" ]]; then
    p4 revert $files_to_revert
fi
p4 change -d $CHANGELIST
```

Comment: Finally uploaded it with some other p4 scripts -  https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts when you want to revert an entire changelist ( as a bulk ) that you've just submitted, and you need to start reverting files of #n-1 one by one fast ( because it's production ) ...

Wanted to support ya23's answer- the link of a Python script - it's really really easy to use ( and really easy to miss his comment )

You give it the revision you want to rollback, and it prepares everything automatically ( each file's #n-1 & merging and everything ) ... you just submit.